# How can I use ANT fileset jars into maven project

Tags: java, maven, ant

I have an ant project with the build.xml like the following which is included a **lib.dir** that contains some jar files

```
<project default="run">
    <property name= ... />
    <property name= ... />
    <property name="lib.dir" value="${basedir}/lib"/>
```

also, this project uses some other jars as follow

```
<path id="javac.classpath">
    <pathelement path="${class.dir}"/>
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="prr-*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
    <fileset dir="${basedir}/someapp/lib/plugins">
        <include name="xxx_*.jar"/>
        <include name="slf4j.log4j*.jar"/>
         ....
        <include name="org.someapp._*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>
```

I want to know how is it possible to convert this project into a maven project?

Comment: The first step for a migration is to follow directory layout of Maven. Second search for all jars you are using the correct coordinates and add them to your pom file also removed the usage of a lib directory completely cause it's the wrong in Maven...

Comment: Thank you, I added the jars into the local repository manually and then add every dependency to pom file.